# Compiled query doesn't recognize 'exists' method

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, play-slick

I am facing a lot of trouble while updating my application from play 2.3.x to play 2.4.11.

I started by updating play-slick from version 0.8.1 to 1.1.1, which implies updating slick from 2.1.0 to 3.1.0.

I have a generic class which aggregates the basic method like *findById*.

The problem I am facing at this moment is:

I had this method working as well:

```
def existsById(id: Long)(implicit s: Session): DBIO[Boolean] = 
    tableReference.filter(_.id === id).exists.result
```

I decided to use compiled queries, so I did as following:

```
private val queryById = Compiled((id: Rep[Option[Long]]) => tableReference.filter(_.id === id))

def existsById(id: Option[Long])(implicit s: Session): DBIO[Boolean] =
    queryById(id).exists.result
```

and now, I am getting an error saying that

> Cannot resolve symbol exists

Am I doing it wrong? or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've "lifted" a `Query` into a `Compiled` you have to use `map` to transfrom it to a diferent `Query`. For example:

```
val existsById = queryById.map(q => (id: Rep[Long]) => q(id).exists)
```